# Rails API saving belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to have below in more of a Rails way.

Given appointment belongs to service:

```
appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)
appointment.service = Service.find(params[:service][:id])
appointment.save
```

What I've tried so far:

```
appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)
appointment.build_service(params[:service])
appointment.save
```

However with this approach I'm getting `ForbiddenAttributesError`

I cannot use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` because in strong params I need to use `service_attributes` but my UI application sends AJAX request without `_attributes` but rather just `service` with its attributes.

I don't really like where Rails enforces you to use `_attributes` popular Javascript frameworks like Angular.js and React.js does not enforce or encourage this pattern after all. Is there a way to override this and still use strong parameters with benefit of using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data you're sending to your controller as well as the implementation of `appointment_params`?

Answer (score 0):

Try just setting the ID.  It would be helpful to see your model file, though.

```
appointment.service_id = params[:service][:id]
```

or

```
appointment.service_id = Service.find(params[:service][:id]).id # if you know service exists...
```